# Alt mappings for vim in urxvt

Tags: vim, rxvt

My mappings which contain `Alt` aren't working in `vim` when using in `urxvt`. They work fine in `gvim`.
An example of such mapping

```
map <silent> <A-h> <C-w><
```

In insert mode when I type `Alt-h`, only `h` is printed. 
How do I need to configure `urxvt` such that mappings containing `Alt` work in vim?
I am using Ubuntu.

Oops I set my modifier as super in urxvt. That's why none of the solutions were working for me. Make sure that you set the modifier as Alt to get the solutions proposed to work.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7501092/79125

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you make an `<A-x>` mapping in Vim when x is a printable character (i.e., not a cursor or arrow key), it tells Vim to expect that character with the 8th/high bit set (aka, add 128 to the ASCII value).

In your example, `<A-h>` means Vim will trigger the mapping when you type è.  The ASCII value of h is 104 (binary 01101000) and when you set the 8th bit of that number, you get è's ASCII value of 232 (binary 11101000).

What happens in urxvt and many other terminals is that the Alt key is set to send the character typed prefixed with the Escape character instead of "adding 128".  In this case, Vim seed `<Esc>h` instead of è, so the mapping isn't triggered.

This leaves you two options:  re-configure your terminal to do something different with the Alt modifier **or** add more mappings to Vim with `<Esc>x` in addition to `<A-x>`.

Comment: Just pointing out that you need to set `Alt` as the modifier in urxvt for this solution to work

Answer (score 3):

If you need to enter non-ASCII text, try changing your mappings in `vim` from `<A-x>` to `<Esc>x`.

If you enter only ASCII text, you may try launching `urxvt` with `--meta8` option, and in `vim` `set termencoding=latin1`.

You may also try other solutions from:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_Alt_key_to_work_in_terminal

Comment: See the [vim-alt-mappings](https://github.com/bruno-/vim-alt-mappings) for automating the Esc maps and an explanation of what will break if you use it (why this is a bad idea).

Comment: setting the termencoding to latin1 is breaking my powerline. Weird characters are appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I am shamelessly posting the [answer given by u/jbaumy93 on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/34fdwf/questionhow_to_make_alt_mappings_work_in_urxvt/cqu7n2z).

Here is what I am using now,

In `~/.Xresources` I am **not** setting `URxvt.meta8: true` as the encoding is breaking when I set it. If I use `set termencoding=latin`, it is messing up with powerline characters. I decided to use the `Esc` mappings as @graywh has posted and using the answer linked above to do so.

Also make sure that the modifier is set as `Alt` in `urxvt`. I have been using `super` as the modifier and none of the posted solutions worked.

Here is the snippet from my `vimrc`

```
nnoremap <silent> <A-h> <C-w><
nnoremap <silent> <A-k> <C-w>-
nnoremap <silent> <A-j> <C-w>+
nnoremap <silent> <A-l> <C-w>>
function! Altmap(char)
  if has('gui_running') | return ' <A-'.a:char.'> ' | else | return ' <Esc>'.a:char.' '|endif
endfunction
if $TERM == 'rxvt-unicode-256color'&&!has('gui_running')
  set ttimeoutlen=10
  augroup FastEscape
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertEnter * set timeoutlen=400
    autocmd InsertLeave * set timeoutlen=2000
  augroup END
  execute 'nnoremap <silent>'.Altmap('h').'<C-w><'
  execute 'nnoremap <silent>'.Altmap('k').'<C-w>-'
  execute 'nnoremap <silent>'.Altmap('j').'<C-w>+'
  execute 'nnoremap <silent>'.Altmap('l').'<C-w>>'
endif
```